# String Format Thymeleaf Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, string-formatting

I using thymeleaf and spring boot to build my web application.
I have problem on internationalization.
I need to change all text on my web application into outer file based (all text include validation).
I have code like this:

> error.required=The {0} is required

My web application have 2 validation.
Validation from modal warning and validation from javascript for bootstrapvalidator.
For javascript, it work fine after I implement [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format#4256130)
But my problem is on thymeleaf.
My question: How do I inject {0} from (The {0} is required) with another string?
NB: I have tried to do something like this but the result is error

```
<p th:text="string.format(#{error.required}, #{label.name})"></p>
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert #{label.name} in {0} inside error.required? In that case, it should be: th:text="#{error.required(#{label.name})}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Thymeleaf to insert a property string inside another one defined with one or more parameters, the construction follows this format:

```
#{multiplestr.parameters(#{text.param1},#{text.param2})}
```

In this case, to insert #{label.name} in {0} inside the error.required text:

```
#{error.required(#{label.name})}
```

[Messages](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#messages) in Thymeleaf